# WPF nested data binding works randomly

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, nested

I have a simple form with several textboxes. I am using a ViewModel as DataContext set from code. In the ViewModel I have a property with name Metadata. This propery changes as the user loads new "Metadata" into the form.

The textbox XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Metadata.ContractMetadata.Utstrackning.VastligasteLongitud, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In the ViewModel when the Metadata property is changed I run OnProperyChanged("Metadata"). Metadata implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, the other classes in the hierarchy does not. Sometimes it works, other times it does not. I have tried running:

```
OnProperyChanged("Metadata")
OnProperyChanged("Metadata.ContractMetadata");
OnProperyChanged("Metadata.ContractMetadata.Utstrackning");
OnProperyChanged("Metadata.ContractMetadata.Utstrackning.VastligasteLongitud");
```

...with no luck.

Comment: The code with so many OnPropertyChanged worked just fine! I just assumed I had tried it... Anyway, is there a nicer way to do it and how come it worked sometimes?

Comment: As far as I know, ChangeNotification works on the bound object only. Utstracking should implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so that you can call Metadata.ContractMetadata.Utstrackning.OnPropertyChanged("VastligasteLongitud")

Comment: The problem is that the bound object is an object I get from a service and I don't want to clutter the implementation of that class with GUI stuff. This is something that would be nice if the framework handled!?

Comment: You don't clutter, you build ViewModels around your models in MVVM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProperyChanged for nested properties is not done the way you are doing it!

Each nested level instance must raise a property changed notification itself.

e.g. Metadata instance should raise "ContractMetadata" property

ContractMetadata instance should raise "Utstrackning" property

and Utstrackning instance should raise "VastligasteLongitud" property.

Comment: Although I didn't end up implementing you solution, I see that this would be a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try NotifyPropertyChanged("...") ?